# How to swap two variables in react setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to see that how easily two variables can be swap in react setState like in JavaScript or any other languages the two variables are swapped like:

```
 temp = a
 a = b
 b = a
```

I tried in setState, but have no success:

```
setState(...function() {
    let a = 1
    let b = 2
    let temp

    temp = a
    a = b
    b = a
    return { a, b }
})
```

Comment: So, is there an issue or question here? Looks like you swapped two values. I don't think the spread syntax is correct, but that may depend on your *actual* state object shape. TBH I don't see what React or React state has to do with swapping the values of two variables. Can you clarify your question/use case?

Answer (score 1):

With React hooks:

```
import React from 'react'

const SwapComponent = () => {
   const [a, setA] = React.useState(1) // init a
   const [b, setB] = React.useState(2) // init b

   const onClick = () => {
      const aTemp = a
      const bTemp = b
      setA(bTemp) // swap a
      setB(aTemp) // swap b
   }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Swap</button>
      <div>a: {a}</div>
      <div>b: {b}</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default SwapComponent
```

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-wave-3l7fk
[image]

Comment: You could also just assign the `a`, `b` values to the other setter directly, i.e. `setA(b)` and `setB(a)`, no need for a temp variable.

Comment: True! I wanted to make the answer as clear as possible